# Access files and its contents in Github repository from Django using REST API

Tags: python, github, django-rest-framework

I'm fairly new to Django. Looking to access folders/files in a github repository, display file contents using REST APIs. Any suggestions/examples are really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are plenty of ways to achieve this but if I were taking on your project I would begin look in to the [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) and using a background worker like [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) to scrape the data you need, using something like [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). The worker would then store the data in some database that you have setup through Django.

Now that you have the data, I would start to build out your Django app and just access the data you need using the regular Django model methods. Having an architecture like this means that you don't need to make the calls to Githubs API while a user is requesting data from your site since it has already been populated in your database.

Comment: I used curl to do it.

Comment: command = 'curl -k --user {user}: pass' + ' ' + file
                    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
                    bytes_out, err = p.communicate()